# Search, edit next line in python

Tags: python

So basically, I am trying to go through a .txt file, find an entry, and then edit the next entry below.

A sample of the text:

```
POINT

8

InvUndamaged

62

253

10

0.279006

20
```

Basically, I need to search for "62", and then replace just the number below it with "256". In this sample that means that "253" would become "256".

```
txt_list = []
with open("X:\- Photogrammetry\Python to Correct DXF Colors\sample.dxf", "r") as x:
    for line in x:
        line = line.rstrip()
        txt_list.append(line)

for i in txt_list:
    if i == " 62":
      x = txt_list.index(i) + 1   
      while x < len(txt_list):
          txt_list[x] = "256"
          x += 1
print(txt_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by creating an empty list, opening the file then appending each line (without a newline) to the list. Then iterate through the list and if an element is "62", then replace the index of "62" in the list +1 and change it to "256"

```
txt_list = []
with open("filename.txt", "r") as x:
    for line in x:
        line = line.rstrip()
        txt_list.append(line)

i = 0
while i < len(txt_list):
    if txt_list[i] == "62":
        txt_list[i+1] = "256"
    i += 1
```